# C++ smart pointer performance and difference with a simple wrapped pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I came across this test that someone did on C++ smart pointers, and I was wondering a couple of things. First of all, I've heard that make_shared and make_unique are faster than normal construction of a shared or unique pointer. But my results and the results of the guy who created the test showed that make_unique and make_shared are slightly slower (probably nothing significant). But I was also wondering, in debug mode for me a unique_pointer is about 3 times slower than normal pointers, and indeed also much slower than a simply wrapping a pointer in a class myself. In release mode the raw pointers, my wrapped class and unique_ptrs were roughly the same. I was wondering, does the unique_pointer do anything special that I would lose if I used my own smart pointer? It seems to be rather heavy, well at least in debug mode it seems to be doing a lot. The test is below:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

static const long long numInt = 100000000;

template <typename T>
struct SmartPointer
{
    SmartPointer(T* pointee) : ptr(pointee) {}
    T* ptr;
    ~SmartPointer() { delete ptr; }
};

int main() {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (long long i = 0; i < numInt; ++i) {
        //int* tmp(new int(i));
        //delete tmp;
        //SmartPointer<int> tmp(new int(i));
        //std::shared_ptr<int> tmp(new int(i));
        //std::shared_ptr<int> tmp(std::make_shared<int>(i));
        //std::unique_ptr<int> tmp(new int(i));
        //std::unique_ptr<int> tmp(std::make_unique<int>(i));
    }

    std::chrono::duration<double> dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "time native: " << dur.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

The link where I found this is at 
http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/memory-and-performance-overhead-of-smart-pointer

Comment: _"in debug mode"_  You should never _ever_ measure and reason about perfomance in debug mode.

Comment: @Revolver Ocelot Yeah, in release mode they all worked out about the same for me at about 4 seconds. Except for shared pointer. I'm wondering though, what sort of magic is that unique pointer doing that it takes three times longer?

Comment: @Zebrafish Then I'm not sure what your actual question is? "Is unique_ptr doing anything special?" That's a bit vague, no? And there's a lot of stuff before that which seems not very relevant.

Comment: @Nir Friedman I was also wondering whether it does much more than what the wrapper class does, I thought I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: memory allocation costs will dwarf any assignment costs. This test is invalid.

Comment: It can contain some data to help debug. Like vector iterator in release mode is literally a pointer, but in debug mode, it probably is a class containing pointer back to parent container and maybe some more info.

Comment: `shared_ptr` does thread-safe reference counting which the other pointers don't do, so it is expected to be slower.

Comment: To my thinking, speed's not the point of the `make_` functions. Safety is. `make_` handles failure cases better than a trivial `new` and store.

Comment: If we remove all irrelevant data from the question (mentions of unoptimised builds and their performance), what's left?

Comment: A `unique_ptr` probably compiles down to a simple pointer when optimizations are enabled. It is basically just *rule-enforcing* syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As best I can tell, the actual question is:

> I was wondering, does the unique_pointer do anything special that I would lose if I used my own smart pointer? It seems to be rather heavy, well at least in debug mode it seems to be doing a lot.

It is possible that `unique_ptr` may have more trivial function calls or something like that, which doesn't get fully inlined, leading to worse performance in debug mode. However, as you said yourself, the performance when it matters, with optimizations enabled, is the same.

Even though `unique_ptr` is the simplest owning smart pointer to write, it still does a lot of things that your trivial wrapper does not:

- It allows custom deleters, while ensuring that stateless custom deleters don't use extra space through Empty Base Class Optimization
- It handles moves and copies correctly
- It handles all kinds of conversions correctly; for instance `unique_ptr<Derived>` will implicitly convert to `unique_ptr<Base>`
- it's const correct

Although most decent C++ programmers can implement a decent `unique_ptr`, I don't think most can implement one that is fully correct. And those edge cases will hurt you.

Just use `unique_ptr`, rolling your own for better performance with optimizations off is not a good reason.

Comment: @Zebrafish Np, if you feel like it fully answers your question,  you can mark it as accepted so that it's understood that the question is resolved.